# Nunit testing with Mock. Instance of Interface

Tags: c#, mocking, nunit, moq, simple-injector

I have the following (simplified) code.

```
public class Controller
{
     private readonly IService _service;

     public Controller(IService service)
     {
         _service = service;
     }

     public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Create(MyObject object)
     {
         var result = _service.method(object);
         if (!result.Succeeded)
         {
            return this.GetErrorResult(object);
         }
     }
}
```

and SimpleInjector is used to inject the dependency between _service and its implementation class, like this:

```
public static void Register(Container container)
{
    container.Register<IService, Service>();
}
```

As a note, injection and unit testing are new to me so I do not fully understand them, but am learning.

If I run the application through Swagger, all is working fine.

As a note, the `Register` function is called when I run the application through Swagger.

Now, I am trying to setup some unit tests using NUnit, and am Mocking the IService object like this:

```
var Service = new Mock<IService>();
Controller _controller = new Controller(Service.Object);
_controller.Create(new MyObject object());
```

which seems to be correct to me so far - although I am not sure?

The problem is that for the unit test, `result` is always null - I think the is because there is a problem with my Mock of the interface - it does not seem to be finding the method - it never steps into it and does not show up int he debugger.

As a note, for the unit test, the `Register` method does not get called. I did try calling it to register the dependency, but it does not help.

As I said above, this is all new to me and I am on the edge of my understanding on all of this.

I am out of ideas and do not know where to look from here, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

The original question had the following:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Create(string content)
```

which I have updated to:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Create(MyObject object)
```

Can anyone advise how I can pass in a generic reference to `MyObject` on the setup, without having to make an instance of this class.

So basically I want to tell it that an instance of this class will be passed in, without creating that instance.

I have tried the following:

```
Service.Setup(x => x.method(It.IsAny<MyObject>())

but it says cannot convert MethodGroup to MyObject
```

and here is the definition of IService:

```
public interface IService
{
      IdentityResult method(ApplicationUser user, UserLoginInfo login);
}
```

Comment: Right. you need to setup the mock to do what you want it to do for the test. Check out the quick start here https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart

Comment: Did you do a Mock Setup on the mock object?

Comment: @Alex, You may need to ditch the simplified example and ask exactly what it is you need. Because we are only going to be left guessing. Looks like you are working with Asp.Net Identity framework which is broad. so please narrow down to specifics

Comment: You won't see your unit tests hit your `Register` method, because your tests don't run that code; they test your Class Under Test in isolation. And this is a good thing: you don't use a DI container while unit testing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to configure the `Mock` object to return something for `IService.method` as follows:

```
var Service = new Mock<IService>();
Service.Setup(x => x.method(It.IsAny<string>())
    .Returns<string>(str => **whatever result you need**);
```

With the addition of your actual `IService` definition, you should change the `Setup` call to:

```
Service.Setup(x => x.method(It.IsAny<ApplicationUser>(), It.IsAny<UserLoginInfo>())
    .Returns<ApplicationUser, UserLoginInfo>((user, login) => new IdentityResult(true));
```

Comment: Please add the definition of `IService` to your question.

Comment: I have posted the IService definition

Comment: thank you - I really appreciate your help. I had this: Service.Setup(x => x.method(It.IsAny<MyObject>, It.IsAny<MyObject>)) - So close!

Comment: @Alex in future provide a [mcve] emphasis on complete so that you can get better answers without a lot of back and forth asking for clarifications.

Answer (score 5):

The setup method has to be called on the Mock object.

```
var Service = new Mock<IService>();
Service.Setup(x=>x.method("argument")).Returns(YourReturnObject)
Controller _controller = new Controller(Service.Object);
```

Answer (score 4):

Using your simplified example

```
public class Controller
{
     private readonly IService _service;

     public Controller(IService service)
     {
         _service = service;
     }

     public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Create(string content)
     {
         var result = await _service.method(content);
         if (!result.Succeeded)
         {
            return this.GetErrorResult(result);
         }
         return Ok();
     }
}
```

Lets assume IService is defined as

```
public interface IService {
    Task<Result> method(string input);
}

public class Result {
    public bool Succeeded { get; set; }
}
```

For the unit test you need to setup the mock to fake the actions wanted for the test

```
public async Task Controller_Given_Content_Should_Return_Ok() {
    //Arrange
    var input = "content";
    var mockService = new Mock<IService>();
    mockService
        .Setup(m => m.method(input))
        .ReturnAsync(new Result { Succeeded = true }); 
    var _controller = new Controller(mockService.Object);

    //Act
    var result = await _controller.Create(input);

    //Assert
    Assert.IsNotNull(result);
    Assert.IsInstanceOfType(result,typeof(OkResult));
}
```

Given that the method under test is asynchronous you would want to setup the test to be asynchronous as well.