# Unit testing a Web API controller

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api, nunit, moq

I am fairly new to unit testing and I am trying to create a unit test for a Web API contoller that I have created which returns a list of brands.

My Web API controller `Get()` method looks like this:

```
[HttpGet("/api/Brands/Get", Name = "GetBrands")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
{
    var brands = await _brandsService.GetAll(null, "Image");
    return Json(brands);
}
```

The generic service method looks like this:

```
public async Task<List<T>> GetAll(
    Func<IQueryable<T>, 
    IOrderedQueryable<T>> orderBy = null, 
    string includeProperties = null)
{
    return await _genericRepository.GetAll(orderBy, includeProperties);
}
```

and the generic repo method looks like this:

```
public async Task<T> Get<TKey>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter = null, string includeProperties = "", bool noTracking = false)

{
    includeProperties = includeProperties.Trim() ?? string.Empty;
    IQueryable<T> query = Context.Set<T>();

    if (noTracking)
    {
        query.AsNoTracking();
    }

    if (filter != null)
    {
        query = query.Where(filter);
    }

    foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties.Split
        (new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
    {
        query = query.Include(includeProperty);
    }

    return await query.SingleOrDefaultAsync();
}
```

This is working and I am returning a list of brands from the database.

Now I tried to create a Unit test for this:

```
[SetUp]
public void Setup()
{
    Brands = new List<Brand>
    {
        new Brand
        {
            Id = 1,
            Name = "Adidas",
            ImageId = 1
        },
        new Brand
        {
            Id = 2,
            Name = "Nike",
            ImageId = 2
        },
        new Brand
        {
            Id = 3,
            Name = "Puma",
            ImageId = 3
        }
    };
}

[Test]
public async Task Get_ReturnsAAListOfBrands()
{
    //Arrange
    var mockService = new Mock<IGenericService<Brand>>();
    mockService.Setup(repo => repo.GetAll(null, null)).Returns(Task.FromResult(Brands));
    var controller = new BrandsController(mockService.Object);

    //Act
    var result = await controller.Get();
    //Assert
}
```

however the result is always null.  Am I testing this correctly or do I need to change my unit test code to verify that the mock service has three items stored?

Comment: I think you need to setup the return of query.SingleOrDefaultAsync(), although you would need to check how to do this as query is not passed in to the constructor. This question may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41611795/nunit-testing-with-mock-instance-of-interface

Comment: thanks @Alex I will check that question out

Comment: yes same problem I am having, GetAll(null,null) does not seem to be getting hit in the debugger

Comment: use the `It.IsAny<T>` methods if the arguments are of no consequence to the test

Comment: @Johann The debugger will not enter the method, you need to simulate the return value using setup.

Comment: @Nkosi I tried this             mockService.Setup(repo => repo.GetAll(It.IsAny<Brand>(null, null))).Returns(Task.FromResult(Brands));
but did not work

Comment: @Alex how do I simulate the return value using setup?

Comment: I would assume the answer from @Nkosi is correct below. The difference between your question and the one linked to above is that the mock object in the linked question above was passed in by the constructor, but in your case the object is created in the method eg IQueryable<T> query = Context.Set<T>();

Comment: @Alex yes most probably Nkosi is right, I need to use It.IsAny<T> however I do not know how to apply it to this         public async Task<List<T>> GetAll(
            Func<IQueryable<T>, 
            IOrderedQueryable<T>> orderBy = null, 
            string includeProperties = null)

Comment: tried to change to the following still did not work though:-             mockService.Setup(x => x.GetAll(It.IsAny<IQueryable<Brand>>, null, null)).Returns(Task.FromResult(Brands));

Comment: You probably want .ReturnsAsync(Brands); insted of .Returns(Task.FromResult(Brands)); As a note,this will still not step into this method, it will just simulate the return type, and instead will return the Brands object you passed in to .ReturnsAsync(Brands);

Comment: @Alex it actually did step into the method, however returned a null object because the mockService is not setup properly

Comment: @Johann you may need to clarify the example in your question.Add some more context around the code snippets you already have to give a clearer picture of how they all fit together. That way answers can be better tailored to your problem. Right now we are left assuming how things fit together

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to configure the setup to expect a particular behavior or argument for the test.

In this case using the `It.IsAny<T>()` to tell the set up what to expect in terms of arguments will allow the test to flow as desired.

Given that the `GetAll` method requires two parameters of 
`Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>>` and `string`, the setup configures what to do based on the values entered for those parameters.

```
[Test]
public async Task Get_ReturnsAAListOfBrands() {
    //Arrange
    var mockService = new Mock<IGenericService<Brand>>();
    mockService
        .Setup(repo => repo.GetAll(It.IsAny<Func<IQueryable<Brand>, IOrderedQueryable<Brand>>>(), It.IsAny<string>()))
        .ReturnsAsync(Brands);
    var controller = new BrandsController(mockService.Object);

    //Act
    var result = await controller.Get();
    //Assert
    //...
}
```

Take a look at the [Moq Quickstart](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart) for a better understanding of how to use this mocking framework

Comment: just as I was going to type that I had solved it, saw your code here :)  Thanks will add this as the anwer!

Comment: yes I have to investigate mocking better, that is why I am doing some examples.  Thanks for your help

Comment: This example helped me a lot to come to the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35565353/moq-returns-with-multiple-linq-expressions

Comment: just one last thing, how can I verify that the result.Count() is actually 3?  My JsonResult does not seem to allow me to see the Data, and I cannot get the Count() from the Value:-              JsonResult actualResult = await controller.Get() as JsonResult;
            var data = actualResult.Data;

Comment: Now it is a little tricky. This is however not the first time I've encountered this. check my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38446754/5233410) and see if it applies to your situation.